# Writing/Reading to storage is not working properly on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

App requests permission from the user upon start and it automatically restarts for that specific OS only. That works properly for the app to detect OBB file. But our game has a downloader system that pulls the files from internet to unlock more levels and it seems like I have to restart the app every time a file has been downloaded for the app to recognize it..any clue?

Yes, indeed the files download (zip files) but the unzipped folders are empty when attempting an unzip.  The folders should have media in them.  For Android OS 6.0 marshmallow.

Comment: `App requests permission from the user `. For what?

Comment: `for that specific OS only. `. For which one?

Comment: What has a downloaded file to do with an empty zip folder?

Comment: For OS 6.0 marshmallow.  We are trying to unzip a zipped file.  So the folder should have images in it.